# How to access and modify the contents of one object created by one script from another script in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 3 scripts written in python.

> 1. an initialization script
> 2. a script that contains a custom data structure class
> 3. a monitoring script.

The initialization script starts first. It creates the object of the custom data structure and then starts the monitoring script.
The monitoring script at certain points will send values to fill up the object that was created in the initialization script.

So, basically there is a global data object created by the initialization script. The monitoring script will add data to that object. The data object is like a buffer which contains tasks to be executed later.

How do I accomplish the task of adding data to the data object from the monitor script?

Example scripts:

initialization script:

```
import monitorscript
import customDataStructure

# creates the object for the customDataStructure
# starts the monitor script
```

custom data structure:

```
class mydata(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1 = None, arg2 = None):
       self.arg1 = arg1
       self.arg2 = arg2

class mydata2(mydata):
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = []
        self.length = 0
    def addTask(self, data): # adds a task to be executed into the buffer.
        self.queue.append(data) # data is a mydata object.
        self.length += 1
    # some other methods.
```

monitor script:

```
# from this script I want to be able to add values to the data object created earlier.
```

If my question is unclear or needs more information, please ask me in the comments.
I might very well be missing a whole programming concept over here. So, if you can tell me what I need to look into, I will be very grateful.

In short, I need to be able to update the data object created by one script by using another script. This data object is a buffer which will be processed separately at regular intervals.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @KSFT I added some code similar to my actual one.

Comment: @KSFT Basically my question is that I have a data object created by one script. How do I update it from another script?

Comment: Why can't you just pass the object to the "monitor" script?

Comment: @KSFT Actually, the data object is like a buffer. I will be adding tasks to it at various points from different scripts that are part of the program. The buffer will be executed at regular intervals of time. So, is the only way to do this is by passing the object to every script that may update it?

Comment: @KSFT There is an answer to this question which also says to pass the object to all the scripts that may update it. I will go with that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you explicitly pass your data structure to the monitor module, you're going to run into issues.  Globals exist at the module level and aren't directly shared, even when you import a resource from one module to another.

Comment: The data object (which is a buffer) will have to be updated from other scripts also apart from the monitor script. So do I pass the buffer to all the scripts that may update it? It seems like it's the best way to do so.

Comment: Yes, explicitly pass it around where you need it to go.